# Does the AWS Free Tier apply across all Regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-limits

If I make four AWS EC2 instances in different regions and keep their combined usage to under 750 hours, do I have to pay for them under the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/)?

Will I remain in the Free Tier of AWS if I do not use the instances more than 750 hours in total?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is specific to customer support / billing. This also isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** 750 free hours per region. It is aggregated across all regions.

See the Regions information at the [Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) FAQ:

> Q: Can I use the AWS Free Tier in any region?
> A: The AWS Free Tier applies to participating services across our global regions. Your free usage under the AWS Free Tier is calculated each month across all regions and automatically applied to your bill. For example, you will receive 750 Amazon EC2 Linux Micro Instance hours for free across all of the regions you use, not 750 hours per region.